# How to make a SPA testable outside of the browser?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I have a SPA that pulls configuration data down from a server and generates a form that a user can proceed to fill out.

I want to be able to make this SPA testable outside of the browser, which would imply that the views and their implementations are not being tested.

Currently, the structure of a form is like so:

```
form
    page 1
        firstName
        lastName
    page 2
        email
```

There is a form model which holds the data of the form and its configuration, and then there is a controller and a view. The controller attaches data from the model directly into the view, and also manipulates the view based on events. The view also has logic for creating and controlling certain aspects, such as inline scrollers (iScroll).

As you can probably see, this makes it impossible to test the code without the browser because the code is so tightly coupled to the view.

I think the way to fix the problem would be to have a controller, a controller model, a view, and then a concrete class that joins them together while providing the form configuration to the controller. But this raises some issues, specifically, that I would then need a factory for creating a controller for the form, pages, and fields, and then something that creates the concrete binder between the view and the controller, and then something that joins them all together in the correct way.

I feel like there has to be a better way to do this.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is AngularJS. There is a template you can clone with git. It has testable capability right out of the box. I don't think there is a need to reinvent the wheel since there is already a well known framework that has this.

Comment: I've looked into AngularJS and I find that it is extremely bloated and slow when dealing with large applications that have a large amount of data. The first thing that comes to mind with AngularJS is its use of requiring modules by defining your function def. with the module in the parameters. I know that requires converting the function to a string and inspecting the text to see what module you need. That's an excess amount of logic for something so simple.